# Default active tab need to be Order info

Tags: magento2

I have added a custom tab in admin order detail page but when I open order detail page then custom tab is displaying by default.

how can I avoid it and display Order info tab by default

```
<referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTabAfter">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom_tab</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">MyNameSpace\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\CustomTab</argument>
                <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">order_transactions</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

The newly added tab is active because of your extension loads before Mage_Sales component. And if you check addTab method in **`Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface\Tab`** class, you will see that logic setup first added tab to active status if active tab does not determine.

To remove active status from new tab we need to modify **`etc/module.xml`** to update depends on. Add sequence to setup component load order.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Module" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

After this modification, **`Mage_Sales`** module will be loaded before your extension and tab interface will setup order_info tab as active.